# How can I show that F(x)=1/(x+2) is contractive mapping?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, numerical-methods

TO show that map is contractive

I think it is contractive mapping on [0.infinity)

However, as x gets closer to 2, it seems that it fails to be contractive mapping.

How can I generalize the interval when F becomes contractive for negative part of domain?

Comment: $|f'(x)| \le {1 \over 4}$ for $x \ge 0$. It is clearly not a contraction in the vicinity of $-2$, not much you can do about that.

Comment: why should it be less than 1/4? Can it be less than any number that is less than 1?

Comment: $f'(x) = - {1 \over (x+2)^2}$. If $x\ge 0$, then $|f(x)| \le {1 \over 4}$. (No number can be less than any number that is less than 1, so I don't know what you mean by this.)

Comment: Oh I see, is it possible for the function to be contractive on some negative part of interval?

Comment: Figure out where $|f'(x)| <1$.

Comment: is that when -1<x?

Comment: That would work. It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to show that iterated sum of fractions is convergent using contractive mapping. Your work helped me a lot Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A large hint. The map is a contraction mapping iff there is $\lambda < 1$ such that $$\vert f(x) - f(y) \vert \leq \lambda \vert x-y \vert$$ 
for all $x, y$ in the domain.

That is, iff $$\left \vert \frac{1}{x+2} - \frac{1}{y+2} \right \vert \leq \lambda \vert x-y \vert$$

i.e. iff $$\left \vert \frac{y-x}{(y+2)(x+2)} \right \vert \leq \lambda \vert x-y \vert$$

Divide through by $\vert y-x \vert$. What can you deduce about whether $\lambda$ exists?

Comment: When (y+2)(x+2)>1 or (y+2)(x+2)<-1 ?